# JavaScript - Function to change ul to display when checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function to change a `ul` from `display:none;` to `display:block;` when the checkbox is ticked.

```
function toggleDelbox(){
    var dgcbt = document.getElementById("removeFromGroup")
    if(dgcbt.checked){
       document.getElementById("remove-from-group-ul").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("remove-from-group-ul").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

The checkbox can be found against every group that gets displayed - the groups returned are based on a search that results in an array and to display them with a checkbox next to them i'm looping through the array like this:

```
foreach ($result as $group) { 
?><input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" id="removeFromGroup" value="<?php echo "$group"?>" onclick='toggleDelbox();'> <?php echo "$group"; echo "<br>";}
<br>
<ul class="remove-from-group" id="remove-from-group-ul" name="remove-from-group-ul">
<input type="submit" value="Delete from group" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the user from the selected group(s)?')" />  <input type="reset" value="Clear Selection">
</ul>
```

So with this if I tick all checkboxes my `ul` changes to `display:block;`, my problem is i want the `ul` to display when ANY checkbox is ticked rather then all of them. I think my problem may have something to do with all the checkboxes having the same ID but i'm hoping i can alter my function so it looks for any tick in any of the elements "removeFromGroup", is this possible and am i tackling this in the right way or would there be a better approach?

Comment: This is not a PHP question. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan Im really sorry but i dont understand how to create a minimal reproducible example, the part of that page titled how to create doesnt actually tell or show how to create?

AndrewL64 im not sure what more html is needed? the only thing missing here is that im starting a form and then closing the form?

Comment: As I said: Click edit, then in the dialog press the `[<>]` button and paste HTML, CSS and JavaScript into the relevant panes. I have given an answer with markup that will work better for you

Comment: Check my answer below, just a css implementation with only classes and no unique IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your code can produce more than 1 element of the same id - please avoid this.
2. if you would add class (ex. `removeFromGroup`) to the input instead of id then in js function you could use `var dgcbt = document.querySelectorAll(".removeFromGroup")` then `dgcbt` would be a collection of inputs.

```js
function toggleDelbox() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.removeFromGroup');
  var shouldShowList = false;
  elems.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {
      shouldShowList = true;
    }
  });
  document.querySelector('#remove-from-group-ul').style.display = shouldShowList ? '' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="removeFromGroup" value="" onclick='toggleDelbox();'>
<input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="removeFromGroup" value="" onclick='toggleDelbox();'>
<input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="removeFromGroup" value="" onclick='toggleDelbox();'>
<ul id="remove-from-group-ul" style="display:none;" >
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>bbbb</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like below perhaps.

This is a test

```css
.remove-from-group {
  display: none;
}

.removeFromGroup:checked~.remove-from-group {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="removeFromGroup" value="">

  <ul class="remove-from-group" id="remove-from-group-ul">
    <li>This is a test</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="removeFromGroup" value="">

  <ul class="remove-from-group" id="remove-from-group-ul">
    <li>This is a test</li>
    <li>This is a test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no, with the given markup this will toggle all the following lists, not only the first sibling list

Comment: Check my example - I have added two lists and two checkboxes, but using the same classname

Comment: This works as long as you add a wrapper for each checkbox and list. You should highlight to the OP that a wrapper is necessary because they are not using it.

Comment: Yeah agree on that. Hopefully OP has the option to add a wrapper for each block.

Answer (score 0):

Premising that all the ID should not be duplicated you could avoid using Javascript and resolve with `CSS`, by toggling *only* the first list after the checked checkbox

```
#removeFromGroup + br + ul { display: none; }
#removeFromGroup:checked + br + ul { display: block; }
```

As a side note, the input inside the list should be contained in a `list-item`

If you're going to change the id by appending a counter, as in my comment below, you can still use CSS

```
[id^="removeFromGroup"] + br + ul { display: none; }
[id^="removeFromGroup"]:checked + br + ul { display: block; }
```

Comment: The ID is duplicated because my list is built from an array that changes in the number of values so im not sure how i could set each value to be unique and then be able to target any of them in the javascript as i wont know the ID?

Comment: You should not use an ID more than one time in a page, it's "illegal"

Comment: You are printing markup inside a for loop: use a counter to append to the id, e.g. `id="removeFromGroup<?php echo $i++ ?>"`

Comment: ok so my ids would be "removeFromGroup1" - "removeFromGroup2" etc... how would i then target any of these in my javascript? can i have a wildcard e.g. document.getElementById("removeFromGroup*")

Comment: @a.smith for this task you should really use only CSS. Are you sure you need to use JS ?

Comment: Agree with Fabrizo on using CSS only for something of this nature unless you have no control over the css and markup

Comment: im only using javascript because i have a working example of something similar. adding the lines above to my css doesnt seem to do anything for me

Answer (score 0):

IDs have to be unique!

Instead use data attributes, delegation and classes

Additionally your HTML is illegal. You need to use LIs in a UL but then you cannot have the checkboxes.

Here is an improved markup and execution. The form will be submitted with the group=group1 if the first delete button is clicked and the confirm approved

```js
document.getElementById("groups").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) {
    document.getElementById(tgt.getAttribute("data-id")).classList.toggle("hide", this.checked)
  } else if (tgt.type === "submit") {
    if (!confirm("Delete from group")) e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="groups">
    <input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="remove" data-id="group1">Group 1
    <div id="group1">
      <button type="submit" name="group" value="group1">Delete from group</button> <input type="reset" value="Clear Selection">
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="remove" data-id="group2">Group 2
    <div id="group2">
      <button type="submit" name="group" value="group2">Delete from group</button> <input type="reset" value="Clear Selection">
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="remove" data-id="group3">Group 3
    <div id="group3">
      <button type="submit" name="group" value="group3">Delete from group</button> <input type="reset" value="Clear Selection">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP to match

```
<form>
  <div id="groups">
  foreach ($result as $group) { ?>        
    <input type="checkbox" name="removeFromGroup[]" class="remove" data-id="<?=$group ?>"><?= $group ?>
    <div id="<?= $group ?>">
      <button type="submit" name="group" value="<?= $group ?>">Delete from group</button> <input type="reset" value="Clear Selection">
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
</form>
```